# Using GotoBLAS2 with C

Tags: c, linker, blas

I'm sort of a newbie to C coding but I've written a Matlab program for simulating neural networks and I wish to translate it to C code because our supercomputer cluster won't allow running more than a few Matlab simulations at once.  To that end, I've found GotoBLAS to take care of the matrix math.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to use it as I don't have a lot of experience in C and using external libraries.  I'm assuming that 'dgemm' is a function in GotoBLAS from reading the BLAS guide pdf.  I've been able to successfully compile GotoBLAS, but when I do:

```
gcc -o outputprog main.c -Wall -L -lgoto2.a
```

I get the messages:

```
undefined reference to 'dgemm'
```

As I understand it, I should be including some `.h` file (or maybe not) from GotoBLAS but I'm not sure which one (or if this is right at all).

Any help with this would be appreciated.  Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a URL for the BLAS Guide you found; modestly extensive Google searching did not show a useful location (or even a hint, really) for the manual.

Comment: The link to the guide is this:  http://www.netlib.org/blas/blasqr.pdf though it's just a list of functions, not a how to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I was able to find the answer on the GotoBLAS mailing list https://lists.tacc.utexas.edu/mailman/listinfo/gotoblas (which is not listed on the website as far as I can see).  Here's a quick step by step on using GotoBLAS2 with C and GCC compiler.

Build GotoBLAS2 libraries (.so and .a), there's good documentation on that included with the libraries so I won't post it here.  Include BOTH of these files in the libs directory of your choice as set by -L.  I was only including one because I thought they were just different versions of the same library which was not correct.

Also link to `-lgfortran` as well if you wish to compile with gcc.  `-lpthread` might also be useful, although I'm not sure, I've seen examples with it but it compiles without.  Your gcc should look something like this:

`gcc -Wall -o outprog -L./GotoLIBSDIR -lgoto2 -lgfortran -lpthread(maybe) main.c`

Finally, call `function_()` instead of `function()`, so for example, `dgemm_()` when using gfortran to compile the fortran interfaces.

Alternatively to the fortran interface the cblas interface can be used as `cblas_dgemm()`.  You still need to link to `-lgfortran` for this as otherwise linking to `libgoto2.so` will fail, and you need to link to that file to be able to use `cblas_dgemm()` correctly.

There doesn't appear to be any need to include any of the .h files or anything else.

Hopefully someone else will find this useful.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 6):

One problem could be that the `-L` option expects a 'directory' name after it, and therefore `gcc` (or the linker invoked by `gcc`) is treating `-lgoto2.a` as a directory.  The compiler does not complain about non-existent directories; it simply ignores them.  Which directory did you expect to find the library in?  (For the purposes of this answer, I'll assume it is in `/usr/local/lib`.)

Another problem could be that the library is not called libgoto2.a.a or libgoto2.a.so or something similar.  You would not normally specify the `.a` suffix.  (For the purposes of this answer, I'll assume that the library is either libgoto2.a or libgoto2.so.)

It appears that you don't need to specify where the headers are found; that means they're in a sufficiently conventional location that the compiler looks there anyway.  If that's correct, the library too may be in a sufficiently conventional location too, and the `-L` option may be unnecessary.

So, you might be able to use:

```
gcc -Wall -o outputprog main.c -lgoto2
```

Or you might need to use:

```
gcc -Wall -o outputprog main.c -L/usr/local/lib -lgoto2
```

---

After some extensive discussion in the comments, and the information that the library is in the current directory and named `libgoto2.a` and that the symbol `dgemm` is still missing, I downloaded [GotoBLAS2 version 1.13](http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/tacc-projects/gotoblas2/downloads) and tried to compile it on a semi-supported platform (MacOS X, probably pretending to be Linux, with x86_64 architecture).  The build was not completely successful - problems in some assembler code.  However, poking around at the headers, there is one that looks like giving the solution to your problems:

```
cblas.h
```

In this, amongst many other function definitions, we find:

```
void cblas_dgemm(enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransA,
                 enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransB, blasint M, blasint N, blasint K,
                 double alpha, double *A, blasint lda, double *B, blasint ldb,
                 double beta, double *C, blasint ldc);
```

All the function symbols in the header are prefixed with `cblas_`.  Your code should be using:

```
#include "cblas.h"
```

You should be calling the functions using the Fortran name (in lower case) prefixed with `cblas_`:

```
cblas_dgemm(...);
```

And the correct link line to use is the first option listed above:

```
gcc -Wall -o outputprog main.c -lgoto2
```

---

At a pinch, you could define macros to map the regular (unprefixed) names to the correct C function names, but I'm not convinced it is worth it:

```
#define DGEMM cblas_dgemm
```

or (safer, because it checks the length of the argument list, but more verbose):

```
#define DGEMM(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n) cblas_dgemm(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n)
```

You can then write:

```
DGEMM(a, ..., n);
```

and the correct function would be called.

---

Experimentation with the partially successful build of GotoBLAS2 mentioned above shows that:

- `cblas.h` is not self-contained (contrary to good coding standards).
- `common.h` must be included before it.
- `common.h` includes a lot of other headers:

  - config.h
  - common_x86_64.h
  - param.h
  - common_param.h
  - common_interface.h
  - common_macro.h
  - common_s.h
  - common_d.h
  - common_q.h
  - common_c.h
  - common_z.h
  - common_x.h
  - common_level1.h
  - common_level2.h
  - common_level3.h
  - common_lapack.h
- The following code stands a chance of linking with a complete library:

  ```
  #include "common.h"
  #include "cblas.h"

  void check_dgemm(void)
  {
      double A[33] = { 0.0 };
      double B[33] = { 0.0 };
      double C[33] = { 0.0 };
      cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans,
                  3, 3, 3, 2.0, A, 3, B, 3, 3.0, C, 3);
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      check_dgemm();
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  (In my admittedly broken build of the library, the complaints went from being '`cblas_dgemm()` not found' to a number of other functions missing.  This is a vast improvement!)

Comment: I stumbled upon the GotoBLAS2 mailing list (not found on the project page for whatever reason) at https://lists.tacc.utexas.edu/mailman/listinfo/gotoblas and was able to get an answer, which I posted below.  As such I will remove my comments.  It is actually rather simple once you know what to do :)  Thanks for all your help anyways and for solving the problem of why the compiler wasn't finding the library file!